# imagemagick php library, server error, No data received

Tags: php, imagick

I am using imagick for pdf to image convertion and my code is,

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage(__DIR__.'/test.pdf');
$imagick->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

simply convert file from pdf to image(jpg). but when i use proxy server.

Browser shows

> The connection was reset
>   [image: Error While using Proxy on firefox]

And when i run this without any proxy server it shows

> No data Received.

I am stuck on this where is problem. Please help me. I will be very thankful for every type of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think imagick service not enabled from server side.. please enabled it then check.

Comment: it is working fine for preview the image using this library.

Comment: Use this
    `$im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readimage('document.pdf'); 
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');    
    $im->writeImage('thumb.jpg'); 
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy();`